# Loss of Decimal Value when taking number from form input

Tags: javascript, html, html-input

I am trying to take a value (up to 2 decimal places) from an HTML form Input and then I plan to use that value for some calculations in JavaScript.

The problem i have is when a user inputs in a value, the decimal places are lost.

I have simplified the code below to highlight the issue.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    1st Number<br> <input type="number" step="0.01" id="num1" placeholder=0.00>
  </form>

  <button onclick="calculator()">submit</button>

  <p id="answer"></p>
</body>

<script>
        function calculator(){
            const num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value|0;
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1; 
//example user inputs 5.55, the returned value = 5
        }
</script>
</html>
```

appreciate any guidance on this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You weren't using the proper operator for logical OR, which is `||` (logical) not `|` (bitwise).

Also, you should use `.textContent` instead of `.innerHTML` to set the value into another element since the value retrieved won't contain any HTML. `.innerHTML` has security and performance implications.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    1st Number<br> <input type="number" step="0.01" id="num1" placeholder=0.00>
  </form>

  <button onclick="calculator()">submit</button>

  <p id="answer"></p>
</body>

<script>
        function calculator(){
            const num1 = document.getElementById("num1").value || 0;
            document.getElementById("answer").textContent = num1; 
        }
</script>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

You was casting value to int (internally) using binary operator.

You should [parseFloat](https://developer.mozilla.org/pl/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencje/Obiekty/parseFloat) it instead or use `+` operator to cast it to `Number`

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
  <form>
    1st Number<br> <input type="number" step="0.01" id="num1" placeholder=0.00>
  </form>

  <button onclick="calculator()">submit</button>

  <p id="answer"></p>
</body>

<script>
        function calculator(){
            const num1 = parseFloat(document.getElementById("num1").value);
            document.getElementById("answer").innerHTML = num1; 
//example user inputs 5.55, the returned value = 5
        }
</script>
</html>
```

Comment: JavaScript doesn't have `int`. All numeric data are `number`s.

Comment: That is why I wrote Internally becouse it actually is casted when you are using bit operators. https://medium.com/@zandaqo/bitwise-operators-in-javascript-the-good-parts-a2e811a8c76b

Comment: Than it is casted to Number which is stored as 64 bit float (double)